# IOS Storyboard serialization

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am pretty new to IOS development and ran into few questions.

Assumption: When I use storyboards and I create view in it, storyboard creates a view via init(frame: CGRect) then it serializes it and creates some file that contains this info. When app is launched on a device it uses this serialized data to create objects via init(coder: NSCoder)

Is my assumption correct or I am missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct. Almost. During compilation, *Xcode* will create a `.nib` file for each "view controller scene" in the storyboard. The name of the `.nib` file can be seen by the "object id" property. The nib files are then deployed with your app package.

The `.nib` file contains - among other stuff - the serialized UIView hierarchy, which will be deserialized at run time by the `init(coder:)` initializer.

Btw., When using `.xib` files, Xcode will create a `.nib` file for each `.xib` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, one last question, what is the method that actually called to serialize the UIView, I currently looking through docs and only found `encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder)` but I think that's a bit different cause others refer to `encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder)`

Comment: The view is serialized by Xcode from the xml file, so I personally don't know what is internally used. `encodeRestorableState` is for app state restoration, so you do not save the view but the state of the view (data, edit mode, cursor position, current navigation hierarchy etc.)